# TS: Type inference across multiple interfaces and function signature not inferring?

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference, function-signature

```
type TypeOfSomething = "something" | "other thing";

interface HigherLevel<T extends TypeOfSomething> {
  subsection: MidLevel<T>;
}
interface MidLevel<T extends TypeOfSomething> {
  callback: (arg: T) => void;
}

const t = { subsection: { callback: (arg: "something") => {} } } as HigherLevel;
```

This throws an error (typescript error) [Generic type 'HigherLevel' requires 1 type argument(s).ts(2314)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lC9V1.png)

Full Error: Generic type 'HigherLevel' requires 1 type argument(s).ts(2314)
On the line with `as HigherLevel`

Why is this? I have specified the type of `arg` in the callback function so shouldn't typescript be able to infer the type parameter to `HigherLevel`?

I am using as clause, I get a similar error when using it to type the constant t:

```
const t: HigherLevel = { subsection: { callback: (arg: "something") => {} } };
```

It gives me [the same error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLiih.png)

It would be nice for me to be able to have my types inferred, especially since I am only asking this question as it affects much more complicated typing I am trying to pull off.

I don't know if this is a feature of typescript, but it should be in my opinion or I might be thinking of this problem the wrong way.

Here is a simpler example without the `HigherLevel` interface, which might be easier to solve. I am looking for a solution to the larger problem above still, but this still confuses me:

```
type TypeOfSomething = "something" | "other thing";

interface MidLevel<T extends TypeOfSomething> {
  callback: (arg: T) => void;
}

const t: MidLevel = { callback: (arg: "something") => {} };
```

Same error, same line :(

TS version: 4.7.4 `tsc -V`

Comment: See [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3X7yW) example. `HigherLevel` expects generic argument, it is required, you are notallowed to omit it. If you want to omit, you should specify default generic value like [here](https://tsplay.dev/wXjDQm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally use functions to infer generic types

```
function inferType<V extends TypeOfSomething>(t: HigherLevel<V>) { return t }

const t = inferType({ subsection: { callback: (arg: "something") => {} } })
```

Doubt there's another method

Comment: Yes I have resorted to doing this, with more complicated nested types it can become a bit verbose but I agree, there is no other method